# How to dynamically change the TableLayout in ext.net 1.x

Tags: ext.net

I have an ext.net page containing a table built by `TableLayout`. It is similar with the example shown on the official demo site. ([link](http://examples1.ext.net/#/Layout/TableLayout/Simple_in_Markup/)) The only thing different is I have combo box, textbox inside those `Cell`s, not just a bunch of panels.

Now, there is the need to dynamically hide some textboxes based on the selection of a combobox. What I have done is to set up the combobox to `AutoPostBack="true" OnValueChanged="comboboxname_OnValueChanged"` .

In that code-behind method `comboboxname_OnValueChanged`, I check the selected value and do a `textboxname.Visible="false"`. Then I got the unexpected: the whole `Cell` that contains that textbox is removed. And my whole table is messed up!

Then my guess is that the `Cell` must remain in place to occupy the position. My next try is:

```
mytablelayout.Cells[5].Clear();
mytablelayout.Cells[5].Add(emptyLabel);
```

here, the index 5 is the table cell with the textbox I want to hide. and `emptyLabel` is an `ext.Label` which displays nothing. Unfortunately it does not work.

My third try is to build an empty cell first. then,

```
mytablelayout.Cells.RemoveAt(5);
mytablelayout.Cells.Insert(5, emptyCell);
```

I found `RemoveAt(5)` can be successfully executed, which again messed up my table because the next cell just moves from its supposed place. But the `Insert(5, emptyCell)` just never did what I want.

Now I am really at my wit's end. Can any `ext.net` expert give some advice? How did you manipulate the `Cell`s in a `TableLayout`?

Thank you for any helpful input.

Comment: Why not hide the text box with styles = display:none?

Answer (score 0):

make a CSS class with display none.

```
    .myClass {
                display: none;
             }
```

set the textbox cls property to the CSS class made earlier

```
    textboxname.cls = "myClass";
```